$T$ Pokemon trainers catch a Pokemon every day. How many days does it take until two trainers own Pokemons of the same species?
$T$ Pokemon trainers catch $1$ out of $P$ different species of Pokemons every day.
Every species has the same chance to be caught. 
One species can be caught by one trainer multiple times. 
In mean how many days $D$ does it take until at least $2$ trainers own at least one common species?
I'm looking for a approximative formula which can be computed for large $P$ and $T$ with $T\ll P$ where a simulation can't be done anymore. 
$ \pm 10 \%$ is good enough. 
Proof is not required.

Experiments
I did some experiment with $P=1025$ Pokemon (current count) and different trainer $T$ count to calculate the mean day $D$ required (results need to be round up). Furthermore the median days and the total number of caught Pokemon among all trainer and the median times the trainer count.



T trainer
Mean days $D$ needed
Median day $D$ needed
Total caught Pokemon
Median $D$ times $T$




2
28.8126
27
57.6251
54


3
16.8072
16
50.4215
48


4
12.0491
11
48.1963
44


5
9.44665
9
47.2332
45


6
7.77382
7
46.6429
42


7
6.63424
6
46.4397
42


8
5.83851
6
46.7081
48


9
5.18945
5
46.705
45


10
4.69666
4
46.9666
40


11
4.29345
4
47.2279
44


12
3.95724
4
47.4869
48


13
3.68294
3
47.8782
39


14
3.44168
3
48.1835
42


15
3.24476
3
48.6714
45


16
3.07407
3
49.1851
48




For $T = 2$ trainers we can approximate the mean days $E(D)$ needed with
$$E(D) \approx \frac{\sqrt{P\cdot \pi}}{2}$$
Can we generalize this formula for $T>2$?
Bonus question 1: If we have a look at the total caught Pokemon we see it has a local minimum. The $T$ needed for this local minimum would also be interesting to know.
Bonus question 2: How would the mean days $E(D)$ change if one of those 2 trainer need to be a specific one? E.g the first

Is there a well studied problem related to this? Birthday paradox has some similarities.

After $d$ days, there are $Td$ Pokemon caught, and $\binom T2d^2$ pairs of Pokemon owned by different trainers. Each pair has a $1/P$ chance of being the same kind of Pokemon. These collisions are very unlikely when $P$ is large, and mostly independent, and so (just as in the birthday problem) it makes sense to take a Poisson approximation. That is, we model the number of collisions after $d$ days as a Poisson random variable with mean $\binom T2 d^2/P$.
In this model, the probability that there are no collions after $d$ days is $\exp(-\binom T2d^2/P)$, where I'm writing $\exp(t)$ as a replacement for $e^t$ which makes the power easier to read. If $\mathbf D$ is our random variable - the number of days it takes to see two trainers that share a Pokemon - then it is always true that $$\mathbb E[\mathbf D] = \sum_{d=0}^\infty \Pr[\mathbf D > d]$$ and so our model says that $$\mathbb E[\mathbf D] \approx \sum_{d=0}^\infty \exp\left(-\binom T2 d^2/P\right).$$ If we're happy with an infinite sum as our approximating formula, we can stop here: it is very good. In the table below, the third column shows what this infinite sum gives us for $P=1025$ and $T=2, \dots, 16$; the second column shows the values in the question.



Number of trainers
Mean days needed
Infinite sum
Formula with $\sqrt\pi$




2
28.8126
28.8971
28.8731


3
16.8072
16.8556
16.8812


4
12.0491
12.0833
12.0833


5
9.44665
9.47236
9.47236


6
7.77382
7.8259
7.8259


7
6.63424
6.69152
6.69152


8
5.83851
5.86201
5.86201


9
5.18945
5.22885
5.22885


10
4.69666
4.72961
4.72961


11
4.29345
4.32583
4.32583


12
3.95724
3.99249
3.99249


13
3.68294
3.71262
3.71262


14
3.44168
3.47431
3.47431


15
3.24476
3.26893
3.26893


16
3.07407
3.0901
3.0901



However, instead of taking an infinite sum, we could take an integral approximation. The integral of $\exp(-\binom T2d^2/P)$ with respect to $d$ is an integral in terms of the error function, but because we're going from $0$ to $\infty$, it's one of the few that have closed forms. The estimate this produces is $$\mathbb E[\mathbf D] \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi P}{2 T(T-1)}}$$ but it gives much better results when we add $\frac12$ to it; I assume this can be justified by some sort of continuity correction. I have included a fourth column in the table for the approximation $$\mathbb E[\mathbf D] \approx \frac12 + \sqrt{\frac{\pi P}{2 T(T-1)}}.$$

(+1) Nice answer!

Thank you! I first read only the sum formula and was about to ask for some equation for large $T,P,d$. First tried to find it myself and found some. Upon writing a comment I noticed some answer update. You already answered my question before asking :). Thanks again!

Might you also have an answer to the two bonus questions at the bottom? will add some bounty if yes. Or better as new question?

I don't have intuition about the local minimum, but the second bonus question could be tackled in a similar way to the original - the only difference is that there are $(T-1)d^2$ pairs rather than $\binom T2 d^2$, which leads to a final approximation of $\frac12 + \frac12 \sqrt{\frac{\pi P}{T-1}}$. However, I haven't tested how good this is.

Tested it. It does fit experiment results. Thanks again!

While testing around I got a $T_{min} \approx P^{1/4} \cdot 1.12 + \frac{1}{2} $ for $P = 2^a$ with $a\in [2,44]$ I got an error of less than $1$ to the found true min $T_{min}$.
